# Boolean Property Getter and Setter Locking

Tags: c#, multithreading, properties, locking

Is there any reason why you would create locks around the getter and setter of a boolean property like this?

```
  private _lockObject = new object();
  private bool _myFlag;
  public bool MyFlag
  {
    get
    {
      lock (_lockObject)
      {
        return _myFlag;
      }
    }
    set
    {
      lock (_lockObject)
      {
        _myFlag = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1 for being a school book example

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, you don't need *locks* necessarily - but if you want one thread to definitely read the value that another thread has written, you either need locks or a volatile variable.

I've personally given up trying to understand the precise meaning of volatile. I try to avoid writing my own lock-free code, instead relying on experts who really understand the memory model.

EDIT: As an example of the kind of problem this can cause, consider this code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Test
{
    private static bool stop = false;

    private bool Stop
    {
        get { return stop; }
        set { stop = value; }
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(DoWork);
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Let it get started
        Console.WriteLine("Setting stop flag");
        Stop = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Set");
        t.Join();
    }

    private static void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tight looping...");
        while (!Stop)
        {
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }
}
```

That program *may or may not* terminate. I've seen both happen. There's no guarantee that the "reading" thread will *actually* read from main memory - it can put the initial value of `stop` into a register and just keep using that forever. I've seen that happen, in reality. It doesn't happen on my current machines, but it may do on my next.

Putting locks within the property getter/setter as per the code in the question would make this code correct and its behaviour predictable.

For more on this, see this [blog post by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx).

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the great response.  I found this article which elaborates on your post nicely...  http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/

Answer (score 1):

Reads and writes of bool are [*atomic*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278%28VS.71%29.aspx).

However the name "flag" indicates that separate threads will be reading/writing until some condition occurred. To avoid unexpected behavior due to optimization you should consider adding the `volatile` keyword to you bool declaration.

Comment: Atomic isn't necessarily enough though.

Answer (score -2):

There's no reason to have a lock right there.

Taking a lock may well be appropriate in your design, but it's very doubtful that this is the right granularity.

You need to make your design thread-safe, not individual properties (or even entire objects).

Comment: How do you know there's no reason to have a lock? We don't have any more context. That flag may be all that's required to indicate the a task is "done" for example - and while there are alternatives to locks, simply removing the lock may well cause working code to break. See my code for an example.

Comment: @Jon: You'd want to put the lock around the entirety of reporting the task results, not just one property accessor.  (In any non-trivial design.)  Your example uses the lock as a very expensive memory fence.

Comment: Yes, but there has to be a memory fence of *some* description, and a lock is *one* way of getting that fence. There may well be better ways of achieving the same thing, but your first sentence could be interpreted as "any program which is correct with the locks would also be correct without the locks" - and that's simply untrue.

Comment: @Jon: Reading only the first sentence of my answer would be unwise.  That's frequently true.  While you have given an example where a lock in the property accessor provides a needed memory fence, in probably 99.9% of property accesses from multiple threads, some other action should be done under the same lock, and without releasing the lock in between.  Even when that isn't the case, taking a lock inside a property accessor violates the principle that properties act like variables.

Comment: @Jon: Code that causes delays should be in a method, not a property.  Your example would be significantly better if written as `void MarkComplete() { lock (the_lock) stop = true; } void SpinUntilComplete() { while (true) lock (the_lock) if (stop) return; }` instead of a property.

Comment: Well, I don't think of that as a hard and fast rule, to be honest. After all, *any* code is going to delay the computer to some extent. Heck, when it comes to ORMs, property accesses can do all kinds of things. But that's completely aside from the point of the question: whether the lock hass any purpose. Even reading the rest of your answer, I don't think it's clear that the locks *do* have a purpose in the OP's code, and *do* make a difference.

Comment: @Jon: They have a purpose in your code.  In the OP's code, I don't think it's at all clear that there's a purpose, and I still think there's a high probability that the lock needs a larger granularity to fulfill its intended purpose.

Comment: Maybe - but maybe not. But given that the question is "Is there any reason why you would..." the answer is *yes*. There *is* a reason why you would, in at least some cases. It's not definitely-pointless code, as I maintain your answer implies.